# How can I avoid the need for parentheses in this preprocessor macro?

Tags: objective-c

```
#define mySynthesize(op) @synthesize op = _ ## op;
```

I want to make it so that synsthesize doesn't need the `()`
something like this:

```
#define mySynthesize op @synthesize op = _ ## op;
```

Is this possible and if so how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is not possible - you're trying to mimic the usage of a language construct with a preprocessor macro.

Again, as far as I can tell, not possible.